# Get the categories from category list

Tags: wordpress, categories

I an using now the wp_list_categories function to get the sub categories. like written

```
$featured_catlist_list =  wp_list_categories('title_li=&child_of=' . $term_id .'&echo=0&taxonomy='.$taxonomy_name.'&show_count=0&hide_empty=1&pad_counts=0&show_option_none=&orderby=name&order=ASC');
```

Now i have to get the category name and url. So that i can use that anywhere. Like i can use that in option list. Like any one select any category url redirect to that sub category.

Answer (score 0):

For generating a select with the categories, you can use the following:

```
<?php
    $cats = get_categories();

    if ( $cats ): ?>
        <select>
            <?php foreach ( $cats as $cat ): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->term_id ); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    <?php endif;
?>
```

Just modify the arguments for get_categories as you see fit -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories